# htaccess language prefix redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect all my blog languages into one language. I tried to do it by myself, but no results. Here is an examples:

```
https://mypage.com/de/articles
https://mypage.com/de/articles/some-article-1
https://mypage.com/es/articles
https://mypage.com/es/articles/some-article-1
```

to:

```
https://mypage.com/en/articles
https://mypage.com/en/articles/some-article-1
```

I have also other pages like:

```
https://mypage.com/en/contact
https://mypage.com/es/contact
https://mypage.com/de/kontakt
```

but they need to work like that. So the thing I want to achieve is to use only the English language for all my article pages only.

Comment: please share your current .htaccess

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/(de|es)/(.*)$ /en/$2` should do it.

Comment: I have only a few lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule !^(es|de)/articles/$1 /en/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please do not post additional details in comments. There is an "edit" link below your question, _use it_ ...